# plotly giving incorrect text on hover in stacked bar charts

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly, ggplotly

I'm using `plotly` with RStudio.

`plotly` is giving incorrect text on hover for stacked bars in the chart except for the top most bar.

**Reproducible example**

```
  df <- data.frame(
    make = rep(c('Toyota', 'Honda', 'Volkswagen'),4),
    segment =c(rep('high',3), rep('mid',3), rep('low',3), rep('entry',3) ),
    sales=c( 25,35,75, 35,35,30, 45,25,10, 80, 80, 20)
  )

df
         make segment sales
1      Toyota    high    25
2       Honda    high    35
3  Volkswagen    high    75
4      Toyota     mid    35
5       Honda     mid    35
6  Volkswagen     mid    30
7      Toyota     low    45
8       Honda     low    25
9  Volkswagen     low    10
10     Toyota   entry    80
11      Honda   entry    80
12 Volkswagen   entry    20

  p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=make, y=sales) ) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill=segment), position = "stack")
  ggplotly(p)
```

What I get in RStudio is as in the pictures below. As you would see except for the top stacked bar, everything else is giving the wrong text on hover

**Incorrect text on hover** - based on data in `df` the correct value for `sales` is `20` - instead it is showing `135` - data - `12 Volkswagen   entry    20`
[image]

**Correct text on hover** - only observed for the top most bar in stack.
[image]

```
> packageVersion('ggplot2')
[1] ‘2.2.1’
> packageVersion('plotly')
[1] ‘4.5.6’
>
```

Comment: it's the correct stack value.

Comment: @MLavoie - it should have shown `20`, instead it is showing `135` - how is this correct ?

Comment: stack! just add-up the first three starting from the top

Comment: @MLavoie how do I get `20` to be displayed instead of the sum - ie. individual values for each bar - what kind of chart in `plotly` can give it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you could try adding it with:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=make, y=sales, fill=segment, text=paste("sales original value", sales))) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
ggplotly(p)
```

and if you want to show only sales, you can also use:

```
ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("text"))
```

using Shiny:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({  
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=make, y=sales, fill=segment, text=paste("sales original value:", sales))) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("text"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: great !! how would you use `tooltip` with `renderPlotly` ?